# How i can unhide all Object childrens?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

i have a unity game and Object childrens are hidden. How i can unhide all Object childrens by pressed on mouse button?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "hidden"? inactive? or actually hidden in the HierarchyView?

Comment: Hidden in game by gameObject.SetActive(false);

Comment: I know nothing of Unity, but have you considered looping through them and calling `SetActive(true)` on each one?  Just a guess

Comment: No. I just want to player clicked on parent and parent inactive childrens will be active

Comment: If you hadnt marked the children specifically as in active. Only the top one. You would just turn on the top one

Answer (score 0):

You could get all children recursively and activate them all using [`GetComponentsInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren.html) and a component that **every** child guaranteed has: `Transform` like

```
// Given parent object
GameObject yourParentObject;

// simply get any Transform component including the parent one itself 
// and anywhere nested below it
// (important!) pass in "true" in order to include inactive ones
foreach(var child in yourParentObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true))
{
    // then set them all active
    child.gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

or if you don't need recursion since the children are **direct** children anyway simply do

```
// This iterates only through all direct children
foreach(Transform child in yourParentObject.transform)
{
    child.gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: I do all like you and nothing happens

Comment: then i seems like one object above your parent object is still inactive? I'd also suggest [Debugging your code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) in order to see if according code is actually executed at all

Comment: parent have 3 childrens.

Comment: code: `using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CatOnClicked : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject catthack;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        foreach(var child in catthack.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true))
        {
            // then set them all active
            child.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
`

Comment: i dont know how to put namespace in stackoverflow

Comment: I'm just a beginner and i don't have enough information about unity/c#

Comment: Don't just copy/paste your unformatted code into a comment.  Edit your question and put it there.  Make sure it gets formatted as code (hint, the `{}` button will be your friend in getting the code formatted)